# Cannot access Keycloak account-console in Kubernetes (403)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, keycloak

I have found a strange behavior in Keycloak when deployed in Kubernetes, that I can't wrap my head around.

Use-case:

- login as admin:admin (created by default)
- click on Manage account

([manage account dialog screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3wuZ.png))

I have compared how the (same) image (**quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.0**) behaves if it runs on Docker or in Kubernetes (K3S).

If I run it from Docker, the account console loads. In other terms, I get a success (**204**) for the request

`GET /realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html/init?client_id=account-console`

From the same image deployed in Kubernetes, the same request fails with error **403**. However, on this same application, I get a success (**204**) for the request

`GET /realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html/init?client_id=security-admin-console`

Since I can call security-admin-console, this does not look like an issue with the Kubernetes Ingress gateway nor with anything related to routing.

I've then thought about a Keycloak access-control configuration issue, but in both cases I use the default image without any change. I cross-checked to be sure, it appears that the admin user and the account-console client are configured exactly in the same way in both the docker and k8s applications.

I have no more idea about what could be the problem, do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `ssl_required = NONE` in **realm** table in Keycloak database to your realm (master)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So we found that it was the `nginx` ingress controller causing a lot of issues.  While we were able to get it working with `nginx`, via `X-Forwarded-Proto` etc., but it was a bit complicated and convoluted. Moving to `haproxy` instead resolved this problem. As well, make sure you are interfacing with the ingress controller over `https` or that may cause issues with keycloak.

```
  annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: haproxy
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue with the following environment variables my Keycloak version is 23.0.4:

```
        - name: KC_HOSTNAME
          value: subdomain.domain.com
        - name: KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL
          value: https://subdomain.domain-name.com/
        - name: KC_HTTP_ENABLED
          value: 'false'
        - name: KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT
          value: 'true'
        - name: KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS
          value: 'true'
        - name: KC_PROXY
          value: edge
```